# Distinguish between foo(int) and foo(Integer) in java

Tags: java, generics, methods, parameters

I haven't been able to find this, though I currently have a usecase where I have a generic type which has a method `foo(int)` and a method `foo(T)`.
For my usecase said type is instantiated with T = Integer, meaning I have the methods `foo(int)` and `foo(Integer)`. 
Whenever I try to call `foo(Integer)` it calls `foo(int)` instead, no matter whether the type is specified, whether I cast or not. The only thing solving it is using a Long instead, which I do not want to do.

Is there any way I can force java to use the `foo(Integer)` method?

Edit:

For once, to answer the comment, I don't think code was relevant here, as what I described was formable enough to understand what I meant.
Secondly, the error was on my end, I apologise. I didn't have the expected behaviour and thought it'd be because of an issue in that regard, especially since my IDE displayed the usage of the `foo(int)` method. I'll be closing this now

A MVCE:

Main.java

```java
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(Main,args);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;


public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        ListView<Integer> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(1, 5, 8, 13));
        Integer t = 5;
        listView.getSelectionModel().select(t);
        System.out.println(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
    }
}
```

sample.fxml

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
</GridPane>
```

You will notice this code works as expected, what I figured out now though is that, since I'm not using java but rather groovy - switching the file endings to groovy and compiling with a groovy compiler makes this program have my described behaviour, which means the issue is groovy related not java related.

Comment: please show the relevant code

Comment: This simple code shows the contrary : `public class Foo<T> {

    void foo (int a){
    }

    void foo (T a){
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo<Integer> foo = new Foo<>();
        foo.foo(Integer.valueOf(5)); // invoke the method with object parameter
        foo.foo(5); // invoke the method with  int parameter
    }
}`

Comment: @davidxxx I think you should wait for OP to provide a [mcve]. Of course we can construct examples which "show the contrary"; but OP is presumably doing something different, and has not explained the problem fully enough for anybody to explain the issue.

Comment: @Andy Turner Agreed. No reason to be hurry.

Comment: @Folling always provide a [mcve]. Code speaks 1000 words, and is free of the nuance of natural language descriptions: prose that is clear to the asker of a question is not necessarily clear to readers; code has well-understood semantics.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your recommendations. However in a MCVE the code works, in the section where I do use it, which I can hardly put in a MCVE it does not work. I suppose I've either found another bug in JavaFX or something on my end is going wrong, however java works as expected, making my question here irrelevant.

Comment: @Folling absolutely a MCVE can "not" work. You say that "Whenever I try to call foo(Integer) it calls foo(int) instead, no matter whether the type is specified, whether I cast or not": that doesn't "work" for what you want to do, but it *does* work according to the language specification; even if you're asking a question about why something doesn't compile, showing the code you're trying to compile would demonstrate the problem. It merely has to allow us to reproduce the behavior that you describe.

Comment: That was my point though, I am unable to reproduce the faulty behaviour in a MVCE. I now figured out that the same code works in java, it does however not work in groovy. I'll add the code I tested in the post for good measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question as stated has a simple answer:

```
class Foo<T> {
    void foo(int i) {
        System.out.println("foo(int)");
    }
    void foo(T t) {
        System.out.println("foo(T)");
    }
}

private void test() {
    Foo<Integer> foo = new Foo<>();
    foo.foo(1);
    foo.foo((Integer)1);
    foo.foo(Integer.valueOf("1"));
}
```

prints:

> foo(int)
>
> foo(T)
>
> foo(T)

However, I suspect you've tried this so please post some example code.

If you like, check out the rules for method selection here:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3.